# How do I retrieve a list of articles and categories programatically in joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, joomla1.6

I need to create a component (front-end) which gives a list of articles and categories in the Joomla site in which it is installed, on being pinged. Calling URL will be something like ...../component/mycomponent?param=getArticleList or getCategoryList.

I need to retrieve a list of those stats in Joomla backend. I can do it by a SQL Query but I was wondering if there is a better (using Joomla classes) way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The JApplication class has functions for that. 
http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/Application/JApplication.html#getBlogCategoryCount

Comment: the docs say that it has been deprecated as of version 1.5 but do not mention a replacement ?